# ReactJs - Issue in routering the component

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the HashRouter dependency that is mandatory for the project I'm doing and the `<BillingCycle />` component is not appearing on the screen. When I click on the link, the url: `http://localhost:8080/#/billingCycles` appears in the browser but does not change the page, the Dashboard page continues to appear. No error message appears. Did I forget something?

```
import React from 'react'
import { HashRouter, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Dashboard from '../dashboard/Dashboard'
import BillingCycle from '../billingCycle/BillingCycle'

export default props => (
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/billingCycles' component={BillingCycle} />
      <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
      <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
)
```

Below, I have the parent component that imports the `<Route />` component

```
import '../common/template/dependencies'
import React from 'react'


import Header from '../common/template/Header'
import SideBar from '../common/template/SideBar'
import Footer from '../common/template/Footer'
import Routes from './Routes'

export default (props) => (
  <div className='wrapper'>
    <Header />
    <SideBar />
    <div className='content-wrapper'>
     <Routes />
     </div>
    <Footer/>
  </div>
)
```

Down here I have the link component that is clicked to direct to the  component.

```
import React from 'react'
import MenuItem from './MenuItem'
import MenuTree from './MenuTree'


export default props => (
  <ul className='sidebar-menu'>
    <MenuItem path='#' label='Dashboard' icon='dashboard' />
    <MenuTree label='Cadastro' icon='edit'>
      <MenuItem path='#/billingCycles' label='Ciclos de Pagamentos'icon='usd'/>    
    </MenuTree>
  </ul>
)
```

Comment: Can you share with us the Link button thats executing the re-route?

Comment: Kindly share the `MenuItem ` as well.

Comment: Sure! I have updated the question and I inserted the component responsible for the click

Comment: Is MenuItem using the Link component from React-Router ?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo No. The menu item is using pure HTML/JSX just like that: export default props => (
  <li>
    <a href={props.path}>
      <i className={`fa fa-${props.icon}`}></i>{props.label}
    </a>
  </li>
)

Comment: @claudiobitar ah gotcha! That explains why you cant re-route, you have to use the Link component in order to navigate from one page to the next and swap components in react-router-dom. See my answer below :)

Comment: I will test your solution

Answer (score 1):

In order to re-route using React-Router you need to make use of the Link component which is unique to the library.

First bring in the Link component from the library. Then wrap the `MenuItem` component inside a `Link` like so.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

   <Link to='/billingCycles'>
      <MenuItem label='Ciclos de Pagamentos'icon='usd'/> 
   </Link>
```

Comment: There is a `path` prop on `Link` ? Are you sure you didn't meant `to`?

Comment: @AsafAviv ah you are right! Thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: @Christoper Ngo it didn't work now any page appears neither 'dashboard' neither 'billingCycles'

Comment: @claudiobitar hmm now that is strange. When you click on the newly added Link component, what does the URL path look like?

Comment: there aren't appearing no page so it is impossible to click on links, because the dashboard page is the parent page like index page and it isn't appearing after the code changing